# Stretch Div width to take Bootstrap Container width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want the overlay div to take full container width (`col-md-12`). Now of course, it's only taking up `col-md-4` width which is it's parent.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('button').click(function() {
    $('#overlay').toggleClass('active');
    // calcs bottom of button 
    var bottom = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight(true);
    $('#overlay').css({
      'top': bottom + 'px',

    });
  });

  $('#close').click(function() {
    $('#overlay').removeClass('active');
  });

});
```

```css
#overlay {
  z-index: 10;
  margin-left: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background: #E5E5E5;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 500px;
  display: none;
  left: 0;
}

#overlay.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">ADD GAME</button>
    <div id="overlay">
      <a href="#" id="close">X</a>
      <h2>This is an overlay</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `position: static;` to `.col-md-4` and `position: relative;` to `.container`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('button').click(function() {
    $('#overlay').toggleClass('active');
    // calcs bottom of button 
    var bottom = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight(true);
    $('#overlay').css({
      'top': bottom + 'px',

    });
  });

  $('#close').click(function() {
    $('#overlay').removeClass('active');
  });

});
```

```css
#overlay {
  z-index: 10;
  margin-left: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background: #E5E5E5;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 500px;
  display: none;
  left: 0;
}

#overlay.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<style>
  .container {
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .col-md-4 {
    position: static;
  }
</style>

<div class=container>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">ADD GAME</button>
      <div id="overlay">
        <a href="#" id="close">X</a>
        <h2>This is an overlay</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this I think this may work for you. Am not sure because your **Q** is not that much clear.I have removed `margin-left: 15px` as you have put `left:0;` at the bottom.

```
#overlay {
  z-index: 10; 
  position: absolute;
  background: #E5E5E5;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 500px;
  display: none;
  left: 0;
  right:0;/*Added right attribut to make width 100%*/
  top: 0;/*Added top attribut to make your div attach to the top of the parent div*/
}

#overlay.active {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

This will only work if the **parent** of the `#overlay` is **positioned as relative**`(position: relative;)` because the absolute position div always depend on its **relative parent** if there is none then it will align according to the **HTML Page**.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding overlay as sibling to `row`

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">ADD GAME</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
<div id="overlay">
   <a href="#" id="close">X</a>
   <h2>This is an overlay</h2>
</div>
```